# Datetimepicker works when I pushed on production but not on local server [ROR 4]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have been using bootstrap datetimepicker.

The strange thing is that it works on the real site but not on local server.

I used cloud 9 as my "local server" as I am developing on ide and use heroku as my host.

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

Verify browser can load html 5 tags, as bootstrap-datetimepicker is pretty new for some browsers. If thats not it, then verify you load bootstrap on both servers.

Comment: I am pretty sure my browser is ok because otherwise I won't be able to load datetimepicker when I test it on my heroku server either.

Comment: But how do I verify if i have loaded booststrap or not?

Comment: try the dev tools of the browser - either check sources or network to see what is loading/loaded